# Java kafka-clients producer fails to send message on queue?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying simple kafka POC with sample producer and consumer.
Message sent from `console-producer` is received at `console-consumer`, but message sent from `java kafka-clients producer` is not received at `console-consumer`.
Below is reproducible,

```
kafka queue version   : 2.6.0
kafka-clients version : 2.6.0
```

Java producer:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer(props);
        try {
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("enricher-co", "POC Message"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            producer.close();
        }
    }
```

Kafka queue setup was done with guidelines provided in https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart .

This is what is working on console,
Console producer,

```
$./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic enricher-co
> Console POC
```

Console Consumer,

```
$./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic enricher-co
Console POC
```

Kindly help.

Comment: any exception occurs?  try to print exception in catch block. so that you get some ideas.

Comment: Code executes  fine with no exceptions. Didn't even see any debug level messages I thought will help.

Comment: It would help to see the console commands that work, for comparison. The code looks OK on the face of it. I think you're producing a message with no key -- I honestly have no idea whether that's significant or not, because I've never tried it.

Comment: You are currently producing messages in "fire-and-forget" mode, so you will not get any answer/Exception back from Kafka. Please add `.get()` to your `send` call.

Comment: @mike -- yes, I know that. I was just wondering whether the lack of a key would affect whether messages were available to the consumer -- since we don't know how the consumer is being run. But I'd certainly agree with the `get()`.

Comment: @mike -- I don't claim to be any kind of Kafka expert, so I don't mind my comments being challenged ;) I work on products that use Kafka, but I don't write a lot of client code myself.

Comment: @KevinBoone -- I just tried capturing RecordMetadata returned by `send().get()`, Which shows positive response, but still message is not actually recived on queue as per queue topic logs.

Comment: @Akshay -- please describe in detail how you are testing whether the message has been received onto the queue. Can you consume anything by running `kafka-console-consumer.sh --from-beginning ...` ? I could easily be overlooking something, but your producer code looks kind-of OK, so far as I can see.

Comment: Yes Kevin. I also tried `kafka-console-consumer` with `from-beginning` option.
As just a shot I downgraded `kafka-clients` version to `2.5.0` same producer is working fine now & `kafka-console-consumer` received message. PS: For making sure that messages are received by queue, I was checking topic logs and console-consumer o/p which is also updated now in question as more context